# Is it weird to use a common given name as a last name?

Tags: names

I have a Chinese name, 藍奕超, which I would like to convert into Japanese.

My last name is apparently a common Japanese feminine first name but I am a male. I was wondering:

a) Is it weird for my last name to be 藍 (あい）

b) Is it weird that my last name is "feminine" and I am a male

c) Would あい or らん sound more natural/feel right/is more "native"?

d) How would I convert 奕超?

Comment: Chinese names are normally pronounced in on’yomi. Going by this custom, your last name would be らん. (Your given name would be えきちょう, although most Japanese cannot read the first character.) What do you mean by “native”? Do you want to sound more Japanese?

Comment: Yes. My priority is for it to sound as Japanese as possible. I am still curious as to what the onyomi reading would be as you told me.

Comment: Yes, and also, since you said most Japanese cannot read the first character, what would happen in that case?

Comment: And is らん a common/normal to Japanese ears?

Comment: We expect Chinese-speaking people to have Chinese-sounding names and らん is not at all uncommon (as a Chinese name). If you prefer あい, that should be fine, too. But people will assume it is らん and you might have to correct them all the time. Sounding like a woman’s name is not a problem. Some Japanese last names do sound like women’s names, like まゆみ and みゆき. It is hard to make your given name sound Japanese. The first character is hardly ever used and the second very rarely in names.

Comment: When we don’t know how to read someone’s name, we simply ask, or guess if we cannot ask them. That happens with Japanese names all the time. In any case, your question may be closed as off-topic.